# Alterar --push-option com hooks

Tags: git

É possível alterar a mensagem do --push-option com hook local na hora de fazer um push?

Exemplo:
Ao rodar o comando `git push origin master`, o pre-push hook injetaria o valor "teste" para o --push-option, alterando o comando para `git push origin master --push-option "teste"`

O objetivo disso é que eu preciso fazer algumas validações locais, antes de executar o push, então no momento de enviar para o servidor, eu injetaria no push-options um token único que possa ser validado do lado do servidor para garantir que essas validações foram feitas.

Answer (score 0):

Para carregar um token dentro do `push-option` uma opção seria dentro de seu `.gitconfig` realizar a seguinte configuração:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode usar [isso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56710289/git-push-upstream-with-dynamic-branch-name-inside-an-npm-script) como referência, dessa forma o token será carregado dinamicamente para dentro do `push-option`